# php/mysql + populate 3 dropdown menu

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, dreamweaver

hey guys i am developing a page where i  populate multiple **drop down  menu** that contain data retrieved from the database but the problem is that i can only populate one **drop down  menu** how to be able to populate multiple one if anyone can help me plz

## func.inc.php

```
<?php
 require_once('db.inc.php'); 

function connect(){
   mysql_connect(DB_Host, DB_User ,DB_Pass )or die("could not connect to the database" .mysql_error());

   mysql_select_db(DB_Name)or die("could not select database");

}
  function close(){

  mysql_close();

  }

  function countryQuery(){

  $countryData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM country");

  while($record = mysql_fetch_array($countryData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $record['country_name'] .  '">' . $record['country_name'] . '</option>';

  }

}

function specializationQuery(){

$specData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM specialization");

  while($recordJob = mysql_fetch_array($specData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $recordJob['specialization_name'] .  '">' . $recordJob['specialization_name'] . '</option>';

  }


}
?>
```

## index.php

```
<?php
  require_once('func.inc.php'); 
  connect(); 


?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>testDroplistdown</title>
</head>

<body>
<p align="center">
<select name="dropdown">
  <?php countryQuery(); ?>
</select>
  <?php close(); ?>
</p>
<p align="left">
<select name="dropdown2">
  <?php specializationQuery(); ?>
</select>
  <?php close(); ?>
</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be closing connection and not doing reconnect. Remove the first close() and give it a try

Comment: i have a question i do not know if you can help me how to make the second **drop down list** appear on the selection of any data of the first one .. can you give me an example or at least make me on the right side of the developing

Comment: You can accomplish this with Ajax only. Something like this: http://pastebin.com/KPKpJ9ST

Comment: sorry man but i am new to the AJAX and i do not know how to work with it but thanks i will read about it and try to do it thanks